# Counting specific words in list with list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count, typeerror

While I was building my web crawler, I met this issue:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
----> 3         count_K = STR.count(keywords)
```

Here is the current code:

```
TNOK_TEMP.append(soup.select('#tbody')[0].get_text())
for STR in TNOK_TEMP:
    for keywords in KEYWORD:
        count_K = STR.count(keywords)
    The_Number_of_Keyword.append(count_K)
```

list "KEYWORD" includes various keywords in same order as corresponding list "TNOK_TEMP".

What I want to do is to use list of keywords to count keywords from list of str.

Any better ways you can offer?

Comment: If you know how `count` works and you know it does not accept a list and you know that `keywords` is a list, what is it that you don't know? How to got through all strings in `keywords` and call `count` with each of them?

Comment: I edited and stopped pretending like I know anything. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keywords` is a list, `STR.count()` accepts a string. If `keywords` is a list of strings, you could insert another for loop

```
for keyword in keywords:
    # count
```

otherwise, if you don't know what it contains, flatten the list and then iterate over all the items, wrapping the `.count()` in a try-except block

```
for keywords in flattened_KEYWORDS:
    try:
         # count
    except: pass
```

Do note that you could simplify your overall logic to something like

```
sum(STR.count(keyword) for keyword in KEYWORDS)
```

-after fixing the `list` to `str` issues.